# For loop printing an unexpected number of times

Tags: java, loops

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[5];
    System.out.print("Please enter five numbers. \na=");
    array[0] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nb=");
    array[1] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nc=");
    array[2] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nd=");
    array[3] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\ne=");
    array[4] = input.nextInt();
    boolean totalIsZero = false;
    for (int i=0;i<array.length ;i++) {
        for (int j=1;i>j ;j++ ) {       
            if ((array[i] + array[j])==0) {
                System.out.println("The numbers " + array[i] + " and " + array[j] + " have a total sum equal to 0.");
                totalIsZero = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!totalIsZero) {
        System.out.print("None of the numbers have a total sum of 0 with each other. ");
    }
}
```

Here is some simple code I just wrote. Its task is to check if the sum between every two numbers in an array (consisting of five numbers) is equal to zero.

The problem I have is that when there are two pairs of numbers, both equal to 0, at the end of the program there is a message for one of the pairs only, not for both, as I expected.

How can I fix that, so the user can read that there are two pairs of numbers equal to 0?

Comment: Also, format your code better?

Comment: @karina What is the problem with the code formatting exactly? First time writing a post here.

Comment: @Borislava Don't use backticks for multi-line code snippets - select the snippet and press Ctrl+K (your post was just edited to do this).

Comment: Thanks. Now I hope someone can actually help me with my question.

Comment: I answered it, but also a quick tip would be to use System.out.println(), rather than System.out.print("/n")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work perfectly because I haven't tested it and I haven't used java in a while, but just create the array the same way you do it in your post, but try the rest for the actual bulk of the function.

```
// various input calls above^ to create array
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
    {
        if(array[i] + array[j] == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("The numbers " + array[i] + " and " +
                               array[j] + 
                               " have a sum equal to zero.");
            count++;
        }
     }
}

if(count == 0)
{
    System.out.println("No sum between any numbers is equal to 0");
}
```

Comment: I just wrote it in python for testing (I find python to be quicker to test with) with the same methods I just showed you and it worked.

Comment: did it work? if so mark this question as answered please